# How can I fix the "undefined reference to" error in cpp, when call for functions in rigidbodytree, like doKinematics, CreateKinematicCache

Tags: c++, eigen, drake

I am a starter of drake. I use urdf parser to extract my robot model to RigidBodyTree. Then I use doKinematics function to create kinematic cache. However, the builder give me the error below.
This is one case, in some cases, I cannot use other functions in the file rigid_body_tree.cc, and errors are almost the same one.

> - OS:Ubuntu 16.04
> - Language: C++    -GCC 5.4.0    -Clang 6.0.0    -Python 2.7.12
> - Built from source
>
>   - Bazel 0.28.1
>   - Bazel C++ compiler   +capture_cc_env=external/drake/tools/cc_toolchain/capture_cc.env     +source external/drake/tools/cc_toolchain/capture_cc.env     ++BAZEL_CC=/usr/bin/gcc     ++BAZEL_CC_FLAGS=     +/usr/bin/gcc --version     gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
>   - Git revision: 800d961
>   - Build drake using the method on the first page of drake document, 
>       "installation and quickstart

```
auto tree = new RigidBodyTree<double>();  
Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1> q_in, qd_in;  
q_in << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;  
qd_in << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;  
auto kinematics = tree->doKinematics(q_in, qd_in);

Error info:
test.pic.o:test.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'KinematicsCache<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1, 0, 9, 1>::Scalar> RigidBodyTree<double>::doKinematics<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1, 0, 9, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1, 0, 9, 1> >(Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1, 0, 9, 1> > const&, Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1, 0, 9, 1> > const&, bool) const'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1> q_in, qd_in;
```

to

```
Eigen::VectorXd q_in(9);
Eigen::VectorXd qd_in(9);
```

The problem is that we explicitly instantiate the template for `doKinematics` in https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/004864a1ef09583754b8573f287fd2658d18aab3/attic/multibody/rigid_body_tree.cc#L3878-L3884, and it doesn't include the template with type `Eigen::Matrix<double, 9, 1>`. Hence the linker cannot find a reference. But we do instantiate the template with type `Eigen::VectorXd`.

BTW, `RigidBodyPlant` is deprecated. We recommend the user to try `MultibodyPlant` instead.